# Expression to extract country name?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of coefficients for countries, where each coefficient looks like:

`s = "C(Country)[T.China]"`

`s2 = "C(Country)[T.Italy]"`

`s3 = "C(Country)[T.United States]"`

How would I go about extracting just the country name (i.e: "China" or "Italy"?)

And can this be done with a "strip" command instead of regex?

Comment: I don't know much python but looks like you can just extract the substring from the 12th position to the (n-1)th position where `n` is the length of the string.

Comment: Yep this works! Damn, very simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

This expression will do the job:

```
re.findall('T.([a-z|A-Z]*)',s)
```

Comment: Apologies for not including (just edited my question) but some names are like "United States" or "El Salvador" and it cuts off the second word

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe this simple expression would work:

```
T\.\s*([^]]+)
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"T\.\s*([^]]+)"

test_str = ("C(Country)[T.China]\n"
    "C(Country)[T.Italy]\n"
    "C(Country)[T.United States]")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['China', 'Italy', 'United States']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nMJ9et/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.